# how to add tokens in vocab.txt which decoded as [UNK] bert tokenizer

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

i was decoding the tokenized tokens from **bert tokenizer** and it was giving **[UNK]** for € symbol. but i tried by add ##€ token in vocab.txt file. but it was not reflected in prediction result was same as previous it was giving [UNK] again. please let me know to solve this problem did i need to **fine tune** the model for again to reflect the changes in **prediction**. till now i was avoiding fine tuning again because it takes more than 10 hours.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share the code that you used to add the token to the vocabulary. Can you please provide Minimal reproducible example? (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [add_tokens](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.5.1/internal/tokenization_utils.html?highlight=add_tokens#transformers.tokenization_utils_base.SpecialTokensMixin.add_tokens) function of the tokenizer to avoid unknown tokens:

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer
t = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
print(t.tokenize("This is an example with an emoji ."))
t.add_tokens([''])
print(t.tokenize("This is an example with an emoji ."))
```

Output:

```
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'with', 'an', 'em', '##oj', '##i', '[UNK]', '.']
['this', 'is', 'an', 'example', 'with', 'an', 'em', '##oj', '##i', '', '.']
```

Please keep in mind that you also need to resize your model to introduce this to the new token with [resize_token_embeddings](https://huggingface.co/transformers/v4.5.1/main_classes/model.html#transformers.PreTrainedModel.resize_token_embeddings):

```
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(t))
```

Comment: Thanks, @cronoik for the help, I will definitely try this in future, but currently, I have added that word in the vocab.txt file and fine-tuned the model again. it solved my problem. but your idea is also very good to save time.

Comment: I've found that https://github.com/huggingface/tokenizers/issues/615 and https://medium.com/@pierre_guillou/nlp-how-to-add-a-domain-specific-vocabulary-new-tokens-to-a-subword-tokenizer-already-trained-33ab15613a41 can provide in detail about how to do and how it works.